# Client X or ClientY has to be read like a pixel with his number. I don't where to add it without giving a syntax error

Tags: html, css, mouseover

It's a simple problem, just an image with an event. The image have to follow the pointer.

```html
<body>
    
    <img  src=https://media.giphy.com/media/MtQxKzhytFsmQ/giphy.gif alt="">
    
    <script> 
        var bodi=document.querySelector("body")

        var imag=document.querySelector("img")
  
        bodi.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e) {
            imag.style.left=e.clientX10px
            imag.style.top=e.clientY 
        })
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: This is basic string concatenation: `imag.style.left=e.clientX + 'px'`. For this to work your image has to be positioned absolutely (`<img style="position:absolute" />`).  https://jsfiddle.net/g2yqjf16/

Answer (score 0):

```
bodi.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e) {
    imag.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
    imag.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
})
```